# Are Avro Java SpecificDatumReaders Reusable?

Tags: java, avro

What is the suggested best practice for the reuse of SpecificDatumReaders? Today I am creating a new SpecificDatumReader to deserialize every record, however this causes significant GC pressure and consumes some additional CPU time. After creating a single SpecificDatumReader and reusing it to deserialize all my records I observed a significant decrease in gc allocations and a reduction in CPU usage.

I would just like to get some clarity on whether reuse is allowed or recommended since Avro javadoc does not explicitly state one way or another.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are reusable. I spoke with an avro expert and verified with unit tests.